# get a value currently displayed in a spinner(Android)

Tags: android

I am writing a program that allows you to select an item from a list of value in spinner.
After the the item has been selected it gets removed.

How do you get the value that is displayed on the spinner while it does not exist in the list?

Comment: you have to explain in detail, because its quite unclear

Comment: Do you want the position? The string? An ice cream?

Comment: I need the string that is currently displayed after selecting. NB: the value has been removed after selection from the adapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may this help you :

```
spinner.getSelectedItem();
```

Comment: Then you can take index of selected item, Item that has been selected can be added to array or stored in other variable, and by using index you can remove that item from spinner